# Multiple Sums at Column Level

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I need to create following report, i tried crosstab but it looks (or i dont know) it only support one level for columns. By level i mean `Count, Amount, XYZ` under `DAYS` columns (30,60,90).
How can i add multiple levels at Column side using **Crystal Reports 9.2**?

I am getting data from following table
`XXXXXX, DEBIT_CREDIT, CCY, AMOUNT, COUNT, OUR_THEIR, SETTLED_OUTSTANDING, DAYS, RATE, YYYYYYYY`
[image]

Comment: Tag the question with the Crystal Reports version that you are using.

Comment: @craig Tag is not available, version has been added

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple levels of columns by dragging the next column to the top of the current one.

Comment: I don't see it working, columns can not be added in the crosstab by just drag and drop, can you show example

Comment: I am sorry at the time, I wrote this the information about your Crystal version was not available.